# Need to avoid using “in PersistenceUnit” while querying on entitymanager

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, entitymanager

I am using jpa and spring, and got an error with below code;

```
@PersistenceContext protected EntityManager entityManager;

     entityManager.createQuery("select c from Theatre c");
```

And take this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Theatre is
not mapped [select c from Theatre c]
```

In order to solve the problem i use below, but i need any other solution because the project should not know the class and i want to make dynamic programming

```
<class>Theatre </class> in "PersistenceUnit"
```

I appreciate any idea

Best Regards

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, but you don't have Theatre class in your project, or you don't know this class, but you have query "select c from Theatre c"?

Comment: Why don't you want the class known to the query? What is it you are trying to achieve? That is unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute **packagesToScan** in your *LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean* definition (available in Spring 3.1). If you use this approach you don't need to define the *persistence.xml* anymore. The configuration should be something like this:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.sergialmar.domain" />
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
      </property>
      <property name="jpaProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>
```